# Rails 2.3.8: How to functionally test the root route by requesting '/'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, routes

Rails 2.3.8  (testing with Mocha)

In my routes.rb file:

map.root(:controller => 'application',
           :action     => 'render_404_not_found')

In my functional tests I want to verify that a request for '/'
will be handled properly:

```
@controller.stubs(:render_404_not_found).returns(666)
%w( HEAD GET POST PUT DELETE ).each do |method|
  @request = ActionController::TestRequest.new
  @request.env['REQUEST_URI'] = uri
  @request.path = uri
  process(uri, nil, nil, nil, method)
  assert_response(666,
                  "Request for '#{method} #{uri}'" +
                  'should have 404ed (or 666ed)')
end
```

I realise the stub 'returns' clause is incorrect, but I haven't
gotten there yet:

```
test_bogus_uri_path(EdgeConditionsTest):
ActionController::RoutingError: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ \
actionpack-2.3.8/lib /action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:420: \
in `generate': No route matches {:controller=>"application", :action=>"/"}
```

So how do I test that this route is working and invoking #render_404_not_found ?

Thanks!

---

**Final solution based on @noodl's excellent suggestions:**

```
uri = '/'
%w( HEAD GET POST PUT DELETE ).each do |method|
  assert_routing({
                    :method     => method.downcase,
                    :path       => uri
                  },
                  {
                    :controller => 'application',
                    :action     => 'render_404_not_found'
                  },
                  {},
                  {},
                  "'#{method} #{uri}': " +
                  'Root route #failed')
end

#
# Now, ensure that our function is actually getting called..
#
%w( HEAD GET POST PUT DELETE ).each do |method|
  send(method.downcase.to_sym, uri)
  assert_response(404,
                   "Request for '#{method} #{uri}'" +
                   'should have 404ed')
  assert_template('404.html')
end
```

Comment: I think you might have issues trying to route to the ApplicationController. I don't think it handles requests.

Comment: Actually, the route works fine (my `application_controller.rb` has the requisite method and it gets invoked as expected).  It's the writing of the test to ensure it **stays** working that's the question..

Comment: Your question doesn't include the definition of the uri local variable (or the rest of the functional test definition). I know you're beardy enough to not have screwed that up but I can't see anything else wrong. Then again, I've never seen process() used in this kind of test.

Comment: @noodl Above, there's a `uri = '/'`.  Somehow the path is being turned into the action, and hence not matching the root route. :-(  I'm using `process` because the alternative is a messy `eval("#{method.downcase}(uri)")`

Comment: Sorry I'm really not helping here. Could you point me to the definition the process() method call in your test, please? I'm interested, if as unhelpful as ever.

Comment: Possibly less messy: `send(method.downcase, uri)`

Comment: `process` is defined in `action_controller/test_process.rb` and apparently is the helper the 'get' method and friends use.  A complication here is that this test isn't in `application_controller_test.rb` because it's checking edge conditions across all the controllers.

Comment: And no joy with `send(method.downcase.to_sym, uri)` -- same results.  This particular route is independent of the controller; i want to test the **route** is directing to the right place, not that the **controller** is assigned to it..  if that's clear at all. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to test that a request for `/` maps consistently, you'll need to use an integration test instead. In rails' functional tests the various http-method named helpers accept the action name as their argument, not a URI.

[Helpers available to functional tests](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#available-request-types-for-functional-tests)

[Code for the above](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L387)

[Integration test helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing-examples)

Also, [assert_routing](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb#L97)

Comment: `assert_routing` is sweet.  It verifies that requests for '/' __should__ get to the `render_404_not_found` method.  Good enough.  Now I want to test that the method actually gets **called**. Unfortunately, the method does a render (see it at http://pastie.org/1526021), so ISTM the cleanest path would be to stub it to give a different result. Unfortunately, rendering is a 'side-effect' operation rather than a simple method return value, and I haven't figured out how to stub that yet.

Comment: It's probably basic Ruby; set up a stub that executes the alternate render code at the time of execution.  Unfortunately, all my attempts so far have resulted in the code being executed at __definition__ time.  Is there a way of declaring a Proc such that 'treat this block as a literal until invoked with #call' ?  (Making it a distinct __non__-closure, is it?)

Comment: Honestly I'd just create an integration test at this point, run {get,post,head,funk} root_path and check the results with the template rendering assertions. No doubt I'm missing the point again, though.

Comment: No, the rendering assertions may be the solution.